# LINQ to SQL ERROR using Transaction: Violation of PK constraint Cannot insert duplicate key in object '' The statement has been terminated

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions, .net-framework-version

I've had a strange problem using `LINQ to SQL` inside a transaction.

Step to reproduce this behavior:

1. insert a couple of record
2. modify an existing record
3. before to executing `SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict)`, modify the above record on an external application (ex. sqlserver management studio)
4. now SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict) raise conflict error
5. resolve conflict
6. do another `SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict)`
7. here you have the error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint **PK_EmployeeTerritories**. Cannot insert duplicate key in object **dbo.EmployeeTerritories**.The statement has been terminated.

Here is c# code to reproduce this behavior, this code is using `NORTHWIND` database:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (Northwnd db = new Northwnd())
    {
        //=======================================================================================
        // RESTORE PREVIOUS STATUS ==============================================================
        //=======================================================================================
        EmployeeTerritory exitEt = (from et in db.EmployeeTerritories where et.EmployeeID == 5 && et.TerritoryID == "85014" select et).FirstOrDefault();
        if (exitEt != null)
            db.EmployeeTerritories.DeleteOnSubmit(exitEt);
        var existingRegToReset = (from er in db.Regions where er.RegionID == 2 select er).First();
        existingRegToReset.RegionDescription = "Western";
        db.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
        //=======================================================================================
        // RESTORE PREVIOUS STATUS ==============================================================
        //=======================================================================================

        EmployeeTerritory newEt = new EmployeeTerritory();
        newEt.EmployeeID = 5;
        newEt.TerritoryID = "85014";
        db.EmployeeTerritories.InsertOnSubmit(newEt);

        Order newO = new Order();
        newO.CustomerID = "WHITC";
        newO.EmployeeID = 5;
        newO.OrderDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day); 
        newO.RequiredDate= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
        newO.ShippedDate= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
        newO.ShipVia = 1;
        newO.Freight = (Decimal)4.56;
        newO.ShipName = "White Clover Markets";
        newO.ShipAddress = "1029 - 12th Ave. S.";
        newO.ShipCity = "Seattle";
        newO.ShipRegion = "WA";
        newO.ShipPostalCode = "98124";
        newO.ShipCountry = "USA";
        db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(newO);

        var existingReg = (from er in db.Regions where er.RegionID == 2 select er).First();
        existingReg.RegionDescription = "Western1";

        Console.WriteLine("Submit the following update on database using Management Studio:'Update dbo.Region Set RegionDescription='Western2' Where RegionID=2'");
        Console.ReadLine();
        ChangeSet cs;
        using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)))
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    cs = db.GetChangeSet();
                    db.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
                }
                catch (ChangeConflictException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    // Automerge database values for members that client
                    // has not modified.
                    foreach (ObjectChangeConflict occ in db.ChangeConflicts)
                        occ.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepChanges);
                    cs = db.GetChangeSet();
                }
                // Submit succeeds on second try.
                db.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        cs = db.GetChangeSet();
    }
}
```

We need transaction in order to complete some other operations out of the current DB.

Thank you for your help

Fabio

Comment: What is the primary key of the table `dbo.EmployeeTerritories`. This error message suggests that the provided pk already exists in the table: `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_EmployeeTerritories'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EmployeeTerritories'.The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: See my comment RESTORE PREVIOUS STATUS, in that place we have removed EmployeeTerritories PK EmployeeID = 5 && TerritoryID = "85014".

Comment: The problem is this: removing TransactionScope all works fine! How TranasctionScope generate PK duplicate key?